# Renaming columns on slice of dataframe not performing as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to clean up column names in a dataframe but only a part of the columns.

It doesn't work when trying to replace column names on a slice of the dataframe somehow, why is that?

Lets say we have the following dataframe:
***Note**, on the bottom is copy-able code to reproduce the data:*

```
   Value ColAfjkj ColBhuqwa ColCouiqw
0      1        a         e         i
1      2        b         f         j
2      3        c         g         k
3      4        d         h         l
```

I want to clean up the column names (expected output):

```
   Value ColA ColB ColC
0      1    a    e    i
1      2    b    f    j
2      3    c    g    k
3      4    d    h    l
```

---

**Approach 1**:

I can get the clean column names like this:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.str[:4]

Index(['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'], dtype='object')
```

Or

**Approach 2**:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:].columns
[col[:4] for col in s]

['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC']
```

---

**But** when I try to overwrite the column names, nothing happens:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].columns = df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.str[:4]

   Value ColAfjkj ColBhuqwa ColCouiqw
0      1        a         e         i
1      2        b         f         j
2      3        c         g         k
3      4        d         h         l
```

Same for the second approach:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:].columns
cols = [col[:4] for col in s]

df.iloc[:, 1:].columns = cols

   Value ColAfjkj ColBhuqwa ColCouiqw
0      1        a         e         i
1      2        b         f         j
2      3        c         g         k
3      4        d         h         l
```

---

**This does work**, but you have to manually concat the name of the first column, which is not ideal:

```
df.columns = ['Value'] + df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.str[:4].tolist()

   Value ColA ColB ColC
0      1    a    e    i
1      2    b    f    j
2      3    c    g    k
3      4    d    h    l
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this? Am I missing something?

---

Dataframe for reproduction:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,2,3,4],
                   'ColAfjkj':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'ColBhuqwa':['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
                   'ColCouiqw':['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']})
```

Comment: this works i think.. df.columns = [d.split('_')[0] for d  in df.columns] ?

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]` ..?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ChrisA that would work, but it was more about string slicing, the underscore was not a good exampe. I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because pandas' index is immutable. If you check the documentation for [`class pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html), you'll see that it is defined as:

> Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set

So in order to modify it you'll have to create a new list of column names, for instance with:

```
df.columns = [df.columns[0]] + list(df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.str[:4])
```

---

Another option is to use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a dictionary containing the columns to replace:

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[1:], df.columns[1:].str[:4])))
```

Comment: So conclusion is my solution is the most optimal way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Yes, your last approach is the way to go @Erfan

Comment: or `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]` :)

Comment: I see @yatu, thanks. This would be quite lot of manually typing code if the column names were mixed up and 30+ columns. But thanks for the answer

Comment: First dataframe was not a good example. I edited my answer, see new dataframe @jezrael

Comment: Or splitting as @jez suggests is a nice way to solve this particular case, however in the general case, you'll have to define a new list of column names

Comment: Don't you guys think this should at least throw a warning about immutability of the column names? Yatu & @jezrael

Comment: It shoud be nice, :) but not

Answer (score 2):

To overwrite columns names you can .rename() method:

So, it will look like:

```
df.rename(columns={'ColA_fjkj':'ColA',
                   'ColB_huqwa':'ColB',
                   'ColC_ouiqw':'ColC'}
          , inplace=True)
```

More info regarding *rename* here in docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion, this would work, but the point is not to type the names manually. And would be lot of work when you have 30+ columns

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well and came up with this solution:

First, create a mask of the columns you want to rename

```
mask = df.iloc[:,1:4].columns
```

Then, use list comprehension and a conditional to rename just the columns you want

```
df.columns = [x if x not in mask else str[:4] for x in df.columns]
```