# How to use values from a PANDAS data frame as filter params in regex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use the values from a Pandas df as filter params in a SPARQL query.

By reading the data from an excel file I'm creating the pandas dataframe:

```py
xls = pd.ExcelFile ('excel/dataset_nuovo.xlsx')

df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')

print(df1)
```

Here the resulting dataframe:

```
              oggetto                                        descrizione  lenght label        tipologia
0       @iccd4580759@         Figure: putto. Oggetti: ghirlanda di fiori       6   Bad  OpereArteVisiva
1       @iccd3636719@                              Decorazione plastica.       2   Bad  OpereArteVisiva
2       @iccd3641475@                          Scultura.. Figure: angelo       3   Bad  OpereArteVisiva
3       @iccd8282504@  Custodia di reliquiario in legno intagliato e ...       8  Good  OpereArteVisiva
4       @iccd3019633@                                           Portale.       1   Bad  OpereArteVisiva
...               ...                                                ...     ...   ...              ...
59995   @iccd2274873@  Ciotola media a larga tesa. Decorazione in cob...      35  Good  OpereArteVisiva
59996  @iccd11189887@  Il medaglione bronzeo, sormontato da un'aquila...      85  Good  OpereArteVisiva
59997   @iccd4545324@  Tessuto di fondo rosaceo. Disegno a fiori e fo...      49  Good  OpereArteVisiva
59998   @iccd2934870@  Sculture a tutto tondo in legno dipinto di bia...      28  Good  OpereArteVisiva
59999   @iccd2685205@  Calice con piede a base circolare e nodo ovoid...      14   Bad  OpereArteVisiva
```

Then I need to use the values from the `oggetto` column as filter to retrieve for (each record) the relative `subject` from a SPARQL endpoint.

By using this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?object ?description  (group_concat(?subject;separator="|") as ?subjects) 

                            WHERE { ?object     a   crm:E22_Man-Made_Object;
                                                        crm:P3_has_note ?description;
                                                        crm:P129_is_about ?concept;
                                                        crm:P2_has_type ?type.
                                    ?concept    a   crm:E28_Conceptual_Object;
                                                        rdfs:label ?subject.
        
                                    filter( regex(str(?object), "@iccd4580759@" ))    
                                    
                                    }
```

I'm able to filter one single record.

```
  object.type                                       object.value  ... subjects.type                                     subjects.value
0         uri  http://dati.culturaitalia.it/resource/oai-oaic...  ...       literal  Putto con ghirlanda di fiori|Putto con ghirlan..
```

Since the dataset is 60k records I would automatize the process by looping through the dataframe and use the value as filter to have a new df with a relative `subject` col.

```
              oggetto                                        descrizione  subject                                               lenght label        tipologia
0       @iccd4580759@         Figure: putto. Oggetti: ghirlanda di fiori  Putto con ghirlanda di fiori|Putto con ghirlan..          6   Bad  OpereArteVisiva
```

Here the entire script I wrote:

```py
import xlrd

import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

xls = pd.ExcelFile ('excel/dataset_nuovo.xlsx')

df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')

print(df1)

def query_ci(sparql_query, sparql_service_url):
    
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper(sparql_service_url)  
    
    sparql.setQuery(sparql_query)
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

    # ask for the result
    result = sparql.query().convert()
    return json_normalize(result["results"]["bindings"])

sparql_query    =   """     SELECT ?object ?description  (group_concat(?subject;separator="|") as ?subjects) 

                            WHERE { ?object     a   crm:E22_Man-Made_Object;
                                                        crm:P3_has_note ?description;
                                                        crm:P129_is_about ?concept;
                                                        crm:P2_has_type ?type.
                                    ?concept    a   crm:E28_Conceptual_Object;
                                                        rdfs:label ?subject.
        
                                    filter( regex(str(?object), "@iccd4580759@" ))    
                                    
                                    }

                    """

sparql_service_url = "http://dati.culturaitalia.it/sparql"

result_table = query_ci(sparql_query, sparql_service_url)

print (result_table)

result_table.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: From my experience posting your whole dataframe and extensive amount of code does not work well on StackOverflow and asking questions in general. Try to break down your problem in a small step and provide a small example dataframe which is the same as your actual dataframe. It is important to add an expected output as well.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293392/renaming-columns-on-slice-of-dataframe-not-performing-as-expected) is an example question of myself. Notice the easy to read dataframe.