# Efficient way to duplicate pandas dataframe rows and update dataframe values at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, optimization

I need some help to optimize my python code. The code duplicates a single row in the dataframe multiple times based on the value in that row.

I will try to describe what it does:

- The dataframe has three date columns: split date, start date and end date and a status column which holds “in” or “out”. The dataframe will have more columns but the rest are not important in the algorithm.
- It uses the mm/dd of the spilt date to create a list of
  dates between the start and end date. Say the split date is 2000-02-15, start date is 2010-03-26 and
  end date is 2012-12-31. The date list will be 2010-03-26, 2011-02-15,
  2012-02-15 and 2012-12-31.
- Based on the date list, it will duplicate the original dataframe row and
  replace the start date and end date with the dates in the date list.
  Using the same example, the original row will be duplicated
  three times with start date and end date of:

  1. 2010-03-26 and 2011-02-15
  2. 2011-02-15 and 2012-02-15
  3. 2012-02-15 and 2012-12-31
- All newly created rows will take status of “in” except for the last row which will have the same status as the original row. With the same example:

  1. If the status is “in” in the original row then the three duplicated rows will have status of “in”.
  2. If the status is “out” in the original row then the first and second row of the newly created rows will have status of “in” and the third row will be “out”.

I have tried different ways to do the above task and come up with the most efficient code I could think of but I am still not very satisfied with its performance.

I have a huge dataframe with many columns and hundred thousands of row (which is still expanding) and it takes a while to run. Multiprocessing reduces the run time a bit but I think the core algorithm could probably be further optimized.

The task was originally performed in SAS and it was so much quicker there. I am not sure if python is slower than SAS generally or my code is not optimized so your suggestions and views will be very much appreciated.

My python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"name": ["a","b","c","d"],
       "status": ["out","out","in","out"],
       "split_date": ["2000-02-15","2010-12-31","1984-02-29","2000-03-31"],
       "start_date": ["2010-03-26","2010-01-01","2015-06-15","2012-11-18"],
       "end_date": ["2012-12-31","2015-12-31","2020-03-01","2018-07-19"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["split_date"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["split_date"]).normalize()
df["start_date"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["start_date"]).normalize()
df["end_date"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["end_date"]).normalize()



def to_split(df,start_column,end_column,split_column):
    """
    df = name of the dataframe whose dates are to be split
    
    start_column = column name of start date
    
    end_column = column name of end date
      
    split_column = column name of split date (only mm-dd of the date will be used)
    
    """
    
    
    dict_df = df.to_dict(orient="index")
    
    dictionary_list=[]
    
    
    for key,row_dict in dict_df.items():
        
        first_date=row_dict[start_column]
        last_date=row_dict[end_column]
        
                
        if last_date < first_date:
            raise ValueError("end_column_date is before start_column_date.")

        try:
            splitter = pd.Timestamp(first_date.year,row_dict[split_column].month,row_dict[split_column].day)
        except: #leap day
            splitter = pd.Timestamp(first_date.year,row_dict[split_column].month,row_dict[split_column].day-1)                    


        #Create a date list to store intermediate split date between first_date and last_date 
        date_list=[]
        date_list.append(first_date)

        last_boolean=False
        while last_boolean == False:
            if splitter <= first_date and splitter <= last_date:

                try:
                    splitter = pd.Timestamp(splitter.year+1,row_dict[split_column].month,
                                            row_dict[split_column].day)
                except:  #leap day
                    splitter = pd.Timestamp(splitter.year+1,row_dict[split_column].month,
                                                row_dict[split_column].day-1)

            elif splitter > first_date and splitter <= last_date:
                date_list.append(splitter)
                
                try:
                    splitter = pd.Timestamp(splitter.year+1,row_dict[split_column].month,
                                            row_dict[split_column].day)
                except:  #leap day
                    splitter = pd.Timestamp(splitter.year+1,row_dict[split_column].month,
                                                row_dict[split_column].day-1)

            else: #splitter > last_date
                date_list.append(last_date)
                last_boolean = True

        #convert list to dictionary first to remove any duplicate then convert back to list again
        date_list = list(dict.fromkeys(date_list))
        date_list.sort()       
        
        no_segment = len(date_list)-1
        status=row_dict["status"]
        
        for i in range(no_segment):           
            
            #Assign new start and end date to each newly created row
            row_dict["start_column_date"]=date_list[i]
            row_dict["end_column_date"]=date_list[i+1]                     
            
            #Assign new status to each newly created row           
            if i != no_segment-1:
                row_dict["status"] = "in"
            else:
                row_dict["status"] = status
                
            
            #dictionary_list.append(row_dict)
            #results will be wrong because list contains a reference to the original dictionary 
         
            dictionary_list.append(row_dict.copy()) 

    new_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary_list)
            
    return new_df


expanded_df=to_split(df,"start_date","end_date","split_date")
expanded_df
```

Comment: From my experience questions with lot of text and big block of code will not get any answers, no one wants to go through all the text and code to understand what the problem is. Try to keep it short and to the point.[Heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293392/renaming-columns-on-slice-of-dataframe-not-performing-as-expected) a question of myself, see the difference?

Comment: too much to go through - but iterating across a dataframe is always a bad idea. Switch paradigms from looping to best vector based alternatively use masks and subsets

Comment: I am aware that iterating across dataframe is a bad idea. I have tried to use vectorized operation but I don't think it can be used in this scenario as I am actually creating new rows based on input from each row. I might miss something so some pointer on vectorized operation will be great.